# What could a hacker achieve by sending me an email / receiving a reply from me?

Tags: security

I am receiving emails to my website email. I seriously doubt that the person sending the emails are sending them for genuine interest. It sounds to me that it is a hacker trying to get some information about me or my ip address or something as such for hacking person.

my question is: what could a hacker achieve by sending me an email with no attachments assuming I do reply to his email? How could I make sure I am 100% safe from any site hacking attempts?

Thanks

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3674/what-malicious-things-can-happen-when-clicking-on-links-in-email

Comment: What's in those emails? Any links?

Comment: This is much too broad and opinion-based, sorry. Also, it's not about computer software. How to harden your website / server is explained in the respective documentation for your scripts (if you're using third party scripts) and web server.

Comment: Your ip address of your email server is already known.  There is no information that is contained in an email header that could directly lead to a compromise unless your server is already vulerable to an attack which as I said the ip address of said server is already known.

Comment: thank you guys. slhck, I am using my own custom code. What I wanted to know is, does a hacker benefit from knowing my personal IP address, maybe to hijack some admin login session.

Comment: Ramhound, what about my laptop / home  or office ip adress, doesn't a reply from my email help the potential hacker know that? If yes, does this help him in the hacking process

Comment: amiregelz, no, there no links

Answer (score 1):

If you reply then you have admitted that you exist.

He probably didn't know that before.
Stand by for the receipt of huge amounts of spam from everyone to whom he can sell your address.

Comment: So? If they don't receive a non-delivery notification, assuming they send from a genuine email address (which is how it sounds in the question), they know the same. The protocol requires that the MTA send a non-delivery notification which is the reason for some forms of spam (namely backscatter spam).

Comment: if it is only about spam, then I do not feel a big threat there. Anything else should i be worried about?